# Improving run time complexity of insert sort?

Tags: c++, runtime, time-complexity

I've written the following code to try to perform an insert into a sorted vector in O(log n) run-time:

```
std::vector<int> to_insert_sort {2,3,5,6,1,1,3,2};

int to_insert {3};

std::sort(to_insert_sort.begin(), to_insert_sort.end()); //O(log n)

auto pos = std::upper_bound(to_insert_sort.begin(), to_insert_sort.end(), 5); //O(log n)

to_insert_sort.insert(pos, to_insert); //O(n)
```

1) Am I right in saying this operation is O(log n)?

2) Are there ways of performing this operation with increased run-time efficiency?

Comment: The complexity of `std::sort` is not `O(log n)`, it's `O(n * log n)`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort. So I guess the operation is `O(n * log n)` I think

Comment: is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Am I right in saying this operation is O(log n)?

`std::sort` O(n * log n)

`std::upper_bound` O(log n)

`std::vector.insert` O(n)

> 2) Are there ways of performing this operation with increased run-time
>   efficiency?

Yes, you can insert in O(log n) but you'll need to change your data structure. For example, you can use a `std::multiset<int>` instead of `std::vector<int>`.

```
std::multiset<int> m;
//m<={2,3,5,6,1,1,3,2}; //O(n * log n)
int to_insert {3};
m.insert(to_insert); //O(log n)
```